# Python: BeautifulSoup Findall Skip to the Next Tag

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, findall

I am using the following code to write to a csv file.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=F%20Key%20Statistics').read()

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","wb"))
f.writerow(["Name","PE","Revenue % YOY","ROA% YOY","OCF Positive","Debt - Equity"])

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
f.writerow(('Ford', all_data[2].getText()))



name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"})
# find all h2

#print soup.prettify

#h2 div class="title"

print name_company
```

I have found what I want to put in the csv file but now I need to limit it to just, "Ford Motor Co. (F). When I print name_company out I get this:

```
 [<div class="title"><h2>Ford Motor Co. (F)</h2>     <span class="rtq_exch">    <span             class="rtq_dash">-</span>NYSE      </span><span class="wl_sign"></span></div>]
```

I have tried using name_company.next and name_company.content[0]. What would work? name_company uses findall and I don't know if that makes .content and .next null. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find()` to get next `<h2>` tag and use `string` to read its text node.

```
name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"})
for name in name_company:
    print name.find('h2').string
```

---

**UPDATE:** See comments.

```
for name in name_company:
    ford = name.find('h2').string
    f.writerow([ford, all_data[2].getText()])
```

It yields:

```
Name,PE,Revenue % YOY,ROA% YOY,OCF Positive,Debt - Equity
Ford Motor Co. (F),11.23
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I write what's printed to replace "Ford" in this line of code?

    f.writerow(('Ford', all_data[2].getText()))